# Running brew doctor shows I have 7 different python “config” scripts installed. How do I get rid of them so that I no longer receive this warning?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I have had multiple issues in the past with installing python and linking it. I finally used `pyenv` to help me manage my python version. Now the issue is that when I run brew doctor it shows the warning of several config scripts like so;

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python3.7-config
  /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python3.7m-config
  /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python-config
  /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
```

> I am running Mac Os Mojave and I am also using pyenv which has python 3.7.5.

Please, can anyone help me fix/ clear this?

Answer (score 2):

your homebrew install doesn't know how to recitify the shimmed python installs you added through pyenv (which should be expected). Try adding this to your `.zshrc` file:

```
alias brew='env PATH="${PATH//$(pyenv root)\/shims:/}" brew'
```

Comment: @Sensei if this satisfied your need on the question, would you mind adding it as the accepted answer so this question will show as solved? thanks

Answer (score -2):

Unless you’re building Python from source these files shouldn’t cause you any issue: they may confuse `./configure` scripts as the error message tells you, but that’s all.

If you do want to remove them, you can use `rm` to do so:

```
rm /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python3.7-config
rm /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python3.7m-config
rm /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python-config
rm /Users/sensei/.pyenv/shims/python3-config
rm /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
rm /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
rm /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
```